# PyCharm-like console in Visual Code Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, console

I wanted to give VSC a try for developing some Python programs, where I only used PyCharm before. One of the most helpful features for me in Pycharm was the PyDev Console, where I can quickly try small snippets of code (think 3-10 lines), and adjust it to work the way I want it to.

I see VSC has a console, but it's much more like the regular IDLE console, where it's kind of hard to write these snippets of code (fixing something 2 lines prior for example is pretty much impossible).

I've been searching for an extension that'll give me a PyCharm-like console experience in VSC, but have been unable to find one. Is is out there? Or is there another way to get to the same result (like setting up a custom console based on the same PyDev console)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried `Jupyter Notebook` and `Interactive`? There are provided by the `Jupyter` Extension which is bound with `Python Extension`.

Open the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P), with the command of:

```
Jupyter: Create New Blank Notebook

Jupyter: Create Interactive Window
```

You can refer to the [official docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py) for more details.

Comment: Hadn't though about Jupyter! I'll admit it has up and downsides compared to PyCharms PyDev console, but it's definitely doing what I want :)

Comment: enjoyed the answer